# How to set Interface Builder document versioning default to 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface, builder

When I create a new xib in interface builder the Interface Builder Document (Versioning) development parameter is defaulting to xCode 4.1

Is there anyway to default this to xCode 4.2 - The reason I ask is I recently changed a project to use IOS 5 and 4.2 - The project was originally created in 4.1, and when I create a new xib and set the size of the view to "Form Sheet" it generates a waring:

Attribute Unavailable: Form Sheet simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2.

[image: Interface Builder Document property 4.1]

I can fix the warning by changing the Document Version drop down in the property inspector to 4.2

[image: Interface Builder Document property 4.2]

Comment: I am curious to know this too. Is this just a consequence of starting my project in 4.1?

Comment: @Megasaur No, the same thing happens if you start a project in 4.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to modify directly the XCode templates :

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/File Templates/User Interface` - Contains templates when you choose the menu File->New...->New File...

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/User Interface` - Contains templates when you choose the menu File->New...->New Project...

Edit the any xib you want by adding this inside `<archive><data>`:

```
<object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.PluginDeclaredDevelopmentDependencies">
    <string key="NS.key.0">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaTouchPlugin.InterfaceBuilder3</string>
    <real value="4200" key="NS.object.0"/>
</object>
```

Comment: This is obviously the proper answer - why isn't it so marked and rock eye given the Bounty? It is what I was going to say before I read the answer...

Comment: Just gave the bounty to rockeye. Craig needs to mark this as the Answer.